# Android - fragment: InflateException

Tags: android, eclipse, fragment

i'm trying to do a simple exercise about fragments, in Android, but i've some errors and i don't know which is the problem.
The applications consists in 2 fragments, one near the other one, making 2 rectangle (as i said, it only an exercise on the understanding of fragments), so this is my code:

**File**: *fragment1.xml*

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#00FF00" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Questo è il frammento #1"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="25sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

fragments2.xml is the same, from this, it changes only the background color and the text.

**File**: *main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >  

<fragment 
    android:name="com.tia.Fragments.Fragment1"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<fragment 
    android:name="com.tia.Fragments.Fragment2"
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**File**: *Fragment1.java*

```
package com.tia.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,false);
}

}
```

file Fragment2.java is the same, changes only "R.layout.fragment2"

Now, when i try to run it on the emulator i get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tia.fragments/com.tia.fragments.FragmentsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
android:name="com.ita.Fragments.Fragment1"
```

and

```
android:name="com.ita.Fragments.Fragment2"
```

to

```
android:name="com.tia.fragments.Fragment1"
```

and

```
android:name="com.tia.fragments.Fragment2"
```

you misspelled the package name. You could read more about, [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)

Comment: It's an error because the previous project i made was com.ita. I've corrected it, but the problem persists..

Comment: still you wrote Fragments with capital F and in the package is lowercase. Update your code accordingly before asking a question

Comment: On the book where i'm studying from is with capital F. 
I'm sorry but i'm writing and studying what the book says..

Comment: also you should import fragments from the support package. Also, after you modify the layout, I suggest you to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: What an idiot, i've corrected the wrong 'F'... now all works good. Thank you for your patience and for your reply

Answer (score 0):

There's no closing tag for your LinearLayout. The XML is malformed. Remember that every XML file has to have one and only one root element; you have two.

Comment: I don't know why but i haven't copied it here, but there is the closing tag on my code, so the problem isn't it..
Edit: Added right now